# How to access the individual elements of the array through array pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
void
foo (int (*ptr)[10]) {
(*ptr[0])++;
(*ptr[1])++;
(*ptr[4])++;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
int i;
int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
foo(&arr);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
}
printf ("\n");
return 0;
}
```

vm@ubuntu:~/src/tcpip_stack$ gcc test.c

vm@ubuntu:~/src/tcpip_stack$ ./a.out

2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

Aborted (core dumped)

How to access the individual elements of the array through array pointer in foo ( ) ?
Here it seems like, in foo() , based on array index, the entire array is being jumped as many times as index value.

Comment: why not simply use `void foo(int *A)` and call from main: `foo(a)` ...

Comment: The function foo expects an array of 10 *pointers* !

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, it expects a pointer to an `int[10]`. Neither the function signature nor the call is incorrect (although non-idiomatic). It's just the dereferencing of `ptr` that's wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: ooops, right. After 30 years of C++, I still get stuck.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom `void foo(int *A), foo(a)` loses some type checking.  OP's `foo()` expects and an array of 10 `int`, not any size array like `foo(int *A)` would accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dereference `ptr` incorrectly so you instead access non-existing `int[10]`s (out of bounds).

Corrected:

```c
void foo(int (*ptr)[10]) {
    (*ptr)[0]++;
    (*ptr)[1]++;
    (*ptr)[4]++;
}
```

This is in accordance with [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) which says that `ptr[0]` means the first `int[10]` (which is ok),
`ptr[1]` means the second `int[10]` and `ptr[4]` means the fifth `int[10]`, which you then dereference and try to increase the first element in. You must *first* dereference `ptr` (`(*ptr)`), then use the subscript operator.

| Precedence | Operator | Description | Associativity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `++` `[]` | Post increment Array subscripting | Left-to-right |
| 2 | `*` | Dereference | Right-to-left |

This means that your code is equivalent to

```c
void foo(int (*ptr)[10]) {
    (*(ptr[0]))++; // increase the first element in the first (only) int[10]
    (*(ptr[1]))++; // undefined behavior
    (*(ptr[4]))++; // undefined behavior
}
```